# Designing database schema for models with multiple sorts of data

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema, country

This question is about database design and how to best split your
entities when they serve more than one purpose.

My database schema models sports events around the world. What type of
event and sport, when and where it is played, what the participants
are and the winner and so on. One of the entities in the schema is
Country which keeps track of in which country in the world the sport
event took place in.

This works well, but then I also need to add auxilliary data to the
Country model, which is not related to the sport events model per se,
but is required for rendering the data nicely on a web page.

Examples of that data is the countrys flags sprite offset in the
sprite image, a long description of the country, the adjective for the
country (China - chinese etc), number of visitors on the country page
and the subjective importance of the country on a scale from 1-5
(events in countries rated five are shown on the front page).

I could easily put all those attributes on the Country object itself,
but it seems wrong, and pollutes my clean sports event schema. I don't
think the structure of the data should be mixed with details like how
to render it nicely... So the question is how I should organise it
instead?

Answer (score 3):

I would keep this data on a 'Countries' table and create a FK to your sports data.  This will allow you to easily maintain each Country's attributes  as you will only have to update them in one place and the changes will take effect everywhere it is referenced.  I don't think this pollutes your data as the information is relevant to your application.  Furthermore, if you do try to separate this data it will only make your schema more complex and maintenance more difficult.